# Undefined variable: row (View: resources\views\admin\category\show.blade.php)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

hi I wants to show products in categories related to it but it says:

> Undefined variable: row
>   (View:\resources\views\admin\category\show.blade.php)

`blade` file:

```php
@foreach($row->products as $pro_data)
      {{ $pro_data->product_name }}
@endforeach
```

I wrote the above code into show.blade.php

category model:

```
  protected $fillable = [
 'category_name', 'category_description', 'category_slug', 'category_image'
];

public function product()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
}
```

product model:

```
  protected $fillable = [
 'product_name', 'product_description', 'product_image', 'category_id', 'product_code', 'product_price', 'product_status', 'product_slug'
];

public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}
```

category controller:

```
  public function show(Category $category)
  {
    return view('admin.category.show', compact('category'));
  }
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you post your Controller logic code here.

Comment: can you post your controller and model?

Comment: @lizeshakya edited the question

Comment: @BishalJungChettri edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Variable name different

As you can see you have compact the variable name category in Controller.

You are using $row in your blade file

Replace $row to $category in the .blade.php file

```
@foreach($category->products as $pro_data)
      {{ $pro_data->product_name }}
@endforeach
```

2. Relation name different

After changing $row to $category, change your relation name from product to products in the Product model.

*category model:*

```
...

public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
}

...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Category controller  
public function show(Category $category){
    $category = $category->with('product')->get();
    return view('admin.category.show', compact('category'));
  }

// blade
@foreach($category->product as $pro_data)
      {{ $pro_data->product_name }}
@endforeach
```